# Runtime Error in using dfs code

Tags: c++

```
class Graph
{
    long long int V; 
    list<long long int> *adj; 
    bool isCyclicUtil(long long int v, bool visited[],long long int parent);
public:
    Graph(long long int V); 
    void addEdge(long long int v,long long int w); 
    bool isCyclic();
};

Graph::Graph(long long int V)
{
    this->V = V;
    adj = new list<long long int>[V];
}

void Graph::addEdge(long long int v,long long int w)
{
    adj[v].push_back(w); 
    adj[w].push_back(v); 
}
bool Graph::isCyclicUtil(long long int v, bool visited[],long long int parent)
{
    visited[v] = true;

    list<long long int>::iterator i;
    for (i = adj[v].begin(); i != adj[v].end(); i++)
    {
        if (!visited[*i])
        {
        if (isCyclicUtil(*i, visited, v))
            return true;
        }
    else if (*i != parent)
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
bool Graph::isCyclic()
{

    bool *visited = new bool[V];
    for (long long int i = 0; i < V; i++)
        visited[i] = false;
    for (long long int u = 0; u < V; u++)
        if (!visited[u]) 
        if (isCyclicUtil(u, visited, -1))
            return true;

    return false;
}
```

//I have used this piece of code in my program with the function call given below

but when i compile it shows run time error.Please tell me whats the problem
 with this code.

```
int main()
{
    long long int t,n,q;
    cin>>t;
    while(t--)
    {
        cin>>n>>q;


        long long int val[q],i[q],j[q],flag=0;
        long long int count=0,count1=0;
        int hash_s[n] = {0};

        for(long long int t=0;t<q;t++)
        {
             cin>>i[t]>>j[t]>>val[t];
             i[t]=i[t]-1;
             j[t]=j[t]-1;
             hash_s[i[t]]++;
             hash_s[j[t]]++;
             if(val[t]==1)
            {

             count++;
            }
            if(i[t]==j[t] && val[t]==1)
            {
                flag=1;
            }
        }   
        for(long long int t=0;t<q;t++)
        {
            for(long long int l=0;l<q;l++)
        {
                if(i[t]==j[l] && j[t]==i[l] && val[t]!=val[l])
                {
                    flag=1;
                    break;
                }
        }

        if(flag==1)
        break;
        }
        for(int i=0;i<n;i++) 
        {
            if(hash_s[i]>0)
            {
                count1++;
            }
        }
      Graph g(count1); 
        for(long long int t=0;t<q;t++)
        {

                if(val[t]==1)
                {
                    g.addEdge(i[t],j[t]);               
                }
        }
        if(g.isCyclic() && count%2!=0 && count>2 )
        {

            flag=1;
        }
        if(flag==0)
        {
            cout<<"yes"<<endl;
            }   
            else
            {
                cout<<"no"<<endl;
            }

        }
}
```

// Its the function call.  I am using this code to know whether a cycle is there or not in adjacency matrix.
for example 
Let A be the adjacency matrix for the graph G = (V,E). A(i,j) = 1 if the nodes i and j are connected with an edge, A(i,j) = 0 otherwise.

My objective is the one of understanding whether G is cyclic or not. A cycle is defined in the following way:

i and j are connected: A(i,j) = 1

j and k are connected: A(j,k) = 1

k and i are connected: A(k,i) = 1

input
 1 2 1 (i,j,a[i][j]'s value)
2 3 1   (j,k)

1 3 1    (i,k)
so it is cyclic.

```
1      [test case]
3 3    [matrix[n][n],no. of queries]
1 2 1  [i[1],[j[1],val[1]]
2 3 1
1 3 1
```

Comment: Did your debugger tell you anything?

Comment: No in my debugger its running fine.@MichaelWalz

Comment: Well, you didn't post a complete code example so it is difficult to help you. One question could be: How do you ensure that both `i[t]` and `j[t]` is less than `V` ?

Comment: What is the runtime error?

Comment: V is the no. of node . it doesn't have to do anything with i[t] j[t]. i am posting my whole code.@PaulFloyd

Comment: (SIGSEGV)  @PaulFloyd

Comment: @riser I'd assume in your example input you set V to 3. Therefore valid node indices are 0 to 2, not 1 to 3.

Comment: yeah but when i took the input for i[t] and j[t] i have decrease their value by one . so if the input is 1 and 2 they will go as 0 and 1 @orhtej2

Comment: Have you printed the value of `count1` just before `Graph g(count1);` ?

Comment: yeah its coming out to be fine @4386427

Comment: exact input i have given see edit @4386427

Comment: With the input given, the problem can not be reproduced. The program runs fine and produces the output "no" - see https://ideone.com/cwAwBI

Comment: Yeah i know but when i complile it in codechef it says RE.Just not able to figure out why @4386427